# Finding records with junk characters in MS Access SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access, sql-like

I am trying to write an SQL query in MS Access to select where a text column has any punctuation characters except "_", "-","@", ".".

That is an underscore, hyphen, @ and a period are not allowed. Numbers and alphabets are not ok too. Everything else is to be returned

The below is my code:

```
select * from Employee
where name Like '*[!0-9,!a-z,!@,!A-Z,!.,!_,!-]*'
```

However, the above code is not working. Some of the names have "_" an underscore, and that is being selected as well. Any inputs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your like expression is broken. You're currently selecting everything where there's at least one character that's not an underscore (or one of your other characters).

You should invert the condition, not select records where there's at least one character that's an underscore (or one of your other characters):

```sql
select * from Employee
where name Not Like '*[0-9,a-z,@,A-Z,.,_,-]*'
```

Comment: It is still not correct. For instance I have a name like "1&234". This is not being selected from your query. Because it contains numbers, so it doesn't work. I have no idea how to fix this except having multiple Or clauses

Comment: Eh... You said numbers were not okay, so that shouldn't be selected. If you want to allow numbers, remove them from the like clause.

Comment: No it is ok to have numbers, but those names which have '&' should be selected. Your query doesn't select these

Comment: Please provide clear rules, and sample input and output. I don't understand exactly what you want.